# Custom SQL in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I just downloaded the trial of Tableau desktop and this is my first time using the program. I do have a question. When needing to write a custom SQL script, is there only one way to do this? And is it by using the new custom SQL option? The reason I ask this is because it is trying to create a new object in the database, most likely a view. Unfortunately we cannot do this because we only have a read-only account.

[image]

I've worked with SSRS and Visual Studio allows you add your own custom SQL script without creating an object in the database. So, I'm hoping this option is available with Tableau. If not, I will just have to wait until we get our DW up and running.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think tableau creates a object in database... interested to know how you came to that conclusion

Comment: I guess I was assuming it was by the error I was getting: Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

Comment: To the extent I know It doens't mean creating a object, it is trying to connect to database for query execution.. looks like you have provided wrong details for database connection. provide correct details and check It is making a database connection

Comment: But your right, it doesn't create objects. My query has a common table expression. Perhaps you cannot use these in the custom SQL?

Comment: Does this mean are you creating a table in that custom sql ?

Comment: I just came across t he article: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/using-common-table-expressions

Comment: This to me looks like it is needing to create an object in the DB2 database.

Comment: Yup. I can't even create a temp table. This application we have has been so frustrating trying to create reports. I can't wait till we have our DW.  Thanks for chiming in on this!

Comment: Normally table creating access will be prohibited for the tools as these will be hitting the prod databases, Just the queries will be having read only access which can just fetch data

Comment: Siva, you are correct. I don't see tableau creating anything. In regards to the CTE, we would need to create a temp table and then use the temp table  from tableau. The limitations I am experiencing is on our DB2 server and nothing to do with tableau. Thanks for the all the responses. We can consider this case closed.

Comment: We can close but one suggestion is why don't you try using stored procedures in DB2

Comment: I would if we could. We only have a read-only account. We cannot create anything in the DB2 server. Believe me, this has been an extremely painful process. The application we are using has its restrictions. Any changes that need to be done to the data require us to create a custom JAVA class and utilize their XML API. Hence, why we are implementing a data warehouse this year. I can't wait.